# Why does const int main = 195 result in a working program but without the const it ends in a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, constants, program-entry-point

Consider following C program (see live demo [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/556rmrO8S41o2Ul0)).

```
const int main = 195;
```

I know that in the real world no programmer writes code like this, because it serves no useful purpose and doesn't make any sense. But when I remove the `const` keyword from above the program it immediately results in a [segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault). Why? I am eager to know the reason behind this.

GCC 4.8.2 gives following warning when compiling it.

> warning: 'main' is usually a function [-Wmain]
>
> ```
> const int main = 195;
>           ^
> ```

Why does the presence and absence of `const` keyword make a difference here in the behavior of the program?

Comment: According to the standard, this is simply undefined behavior.

Comment: @machine_1 195 is the encoding for the opcode `ret` (return from function) on 8086 and its successors. You can guess what happens when you put that in a variable and call that variable as a function.

Comment: It is probably relevant to link to [How can a program with a global variable called main instead of a main function work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32851184/1708801)

Comment: Did you choose the value on purpose to coincide with `ret` instruction?

Comment: @Ruslan If you do some searching you can find various versions of this in several places. On the stack exchange network [this was one of the older references](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/23397/45595). In my answer to the link above we can find a 1984 IOCCC entry that does something similar but is much more sophisticated.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Observe how the value 195 corresponds to the `ret` (return from function) instruction on 8086 compatibles. This definition of `main` thus behaves as if you defined it as `int main() {}` when executed.

On some platforms, `const` data is loaded into an executable but not writeable memory region whereas mutable data (i.e. data not qualified `const`) is loaded into a writeable but not executable memory region. For this reason, the program “works” when you declare `main` as `const` but not when you leave off the `const` qualifier.

Traditionally, binaries contained three *segments:*

- The `text` segment is (if supported by the architecture) write-protected and executable, and contains executable code, variables of *static* storage duration qualified `const`, and string literals
- The `data` segment is writeable and cannot be executed. It contains variables not qualified `const` with *static* storage duration and (at runtime) objects with *allocated* storage duration
- The `bss` segment is similar to the `data` segment but is initialized to all zeroes. It contains variables of *static*  storage duration not qualified `const` that have been declared without an initializer
- The `stack` segment is not present in the binary and contains variables with *automatic*  storage duration

Removing the `const` qualifier from the variable `main` causes it to be moved from the `text` to the `data` segment, which isn't executable, causing the segmentation violation you observe.

Modern platforms often have further segments (e.g. a `rodata` segment for data that is neither writeable nor executable) so please don't take this as an accurate description of your platform without consulting platform-specific documentation.

Please understand that not making `main` a function is usually incorrect, although technically a platform could allow `main` to be declared as a variable, cf. ISO 9899:2011 §5.1.2.2.1 ¶1, emphasis mine:

> 1 The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of `int` and with no parameters (...) or with two parameters (...) or equivalent; or *in some other implementation-defined manner.*

Comment: Some good points, [zwol touched on some of these here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32851722/1708801) in the comments to my answer to a similar C++ version of this question

Comment: Please include your comment on the encoding for the opcode ret in your answer. This is key to understanding the behaviour described.

Comment: @user19474 Better this way?

Comment: @FUZxxl: nice answer. But ur answer doesn't explain why program exits with garbage value as return status instead of 0? It would be better if you could tell the reason behind it.

Comment: @PravasiMeet The `ret` instruction exits the current function. It does not set a return value. Thus the program exits with whatever was in the `eax` register at the time `main` returned, i.e. a random garbage value.

Answer (score 11):

In C, `main` at global scope is almost always a function.

To use `main` as a variable at global scope makes the behaviour of the program undefined.

(It just *might* be the case that when you write `const` the compiler optimises out the variable to a constant and so your program behaviour is different. But the program behaviour is *still* undefined).

Comment: Nope. A platform may allow `main` to be declared “in an implementation defined manner.”

Comment: I'm too old to trawl through the standard but I imagine it must *always* be a function!

Comment: Cf. ISO 9899:2011 §5.1.2.2.1 “The function called at program startup is named main. The implementation declares no
prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no parameters: (...) or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any names may be
used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared): (...) or equivalent; 10) or in some other implementation-defined manner.”

Comment: OK. Good standard reference! I've amended.