# How does the 64 bit linux kernel kick off a 32 bit process from an ELF

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86-64, 32bit-64bit

By looking at [binfmt_elf.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.5/source/fs/binfmt_elf.c) in the kernel source, I have not been able to figure out what the kernel (64 bit) does differently when spawning a 32 bit process vs a 64 bit process.

Can anybody explain to me what I am missing?

(This question is related to my other question about having 32 bit instructions in the same process as 64 bit instructions ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48854564/is-it-possible-to-use-both-64-bit-and-32-bit-instructions-in-the-same-executable)), but this qualifies as a separate question.)

Comment: Usually the ultimate step is that when transfer is controlled to the process the code selector (_CS_) used will be either for a 32-bit or 64-bit code segment as defined in the descriptor table.

Comment: I can't answer the question, but I can tell you that what you're looking for cannot be in that file because it has to be in an architecture specific file.

Comment: Thanks for the good clues both of you. I have posted an almost complete answer after digging a bit - but I am not entirely there yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the **execveat** system call is used to start a new process, we first enter **fs/exec.c** in the kernel source into the SYSCALL_DEFINEx(execveat..) function.
This one then calls these functions:

- do_execveat(..)

  - do_execveat_common(..)

    - exec_binprm(..)

      - search_binary_handler(..)

The **search_binary_handler** iterates over the various binary handlers. In a 64 bit Linux kernel, there will be one handler for 64 bit ELFs and one for 32 bit ELFs. Both handlers are ultimately built from the same source *fs/binfmt_elf.c*. However, the 32 bit handler is built via **fs/compat_binfmt_elf.c** which redefines a number of macros before *including* the source file *binfmt_elf.c* itself.

Inside *binfmt_elf.c*, **elf_check_arch** is called. This is a macro defined in *arch/x86/include/asm/elf.h* and defined differently in the 64 bit handler vs the 32 bit handler. For 64 bit, it compares with **EM_X86_64** ( 62 - defined in include/uapi/ilnux/elf-em.h). For 32 bit, it compares with **EM_386** (3) or **EM_486** (6) (defined in the same file). If the comparison fails, the binary handler gives up, so we end up with only one of the handlers taking care of the ELF parsing and execution - depending on whether the ELF is 64 bit or 32 bit.

All differences on parsing 32 bit ELFs vs 64 bit ELFs in 64 bit Linux should therefore be found in the file *fs/compat_binfmt_elf.c*.

The main clue seems to be **compat_start_thread**. *start_thread* is redefined to *compat_start_thread*. This function definition is found in *arch/x86/kernel/process_64.c*. *compat_start_thread* then calls *start_thread_common* with these arguments:

```
start_thread_common(regs, new_ip, new_sp,
             test_thread_flag(TIF_X32)
             ? __USER_CS : __USER32_CS,
             __USER_DS, __USER_DS);
```

while the normal *start_thread* function calls *start_thread_common* with these arguments:

```
start_thread_common(regs, new_ip, new_sp,
             __USER_CS, __USER_DS, 0);
```

Here we already see the architecture dependent code doing something with **CS** differently for 64 bit ELFs vs 32 bit ELFs.

Then we have the definitions for __USER_CS and __USER32_CS in **arch/x86/include/asm/segment.h**:

```
#define __USER_CS           (GDT_ENTRY_DEFAULT_USER_CS*8 + 3)
#define __USER32_CS         (GDT_ENTRY_DEFAULT_USER32_CS*8 + 3)
```

and:

```
#define GDT_ENTRY_DEFAULT_USER_CS   6
#define GDT_ENTRY_DEFAULT_USER32_CS 4
```

So `__USER_CS` is 6*8 + 3 = 51 = 0x33

And `__USER32_CS` is 4*8 + 3 = 35 = 0x23

These numbers match what is used for CS in these examples:

- [For going from 64 bit mode to 32 bit in the middle of a process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48855022/5744809)
- [For going from 32 bit mode to 64 bit in the middle of a process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48855906/5744809)

Since the CPU is not running in real mode, the segment register is not filled with the segment itself, but a 16-bit selector:

From Wikipedia ([Protected mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_mode)):

> In protected mode, the segment_part is replaced by a 16-bit selector, in which the 13 upper bits (bit 3 to bit 15) contain the index of an entry inside a descriptor table. The next bit (bit 2) specifies whether the operation is used with the GDT or the LDT. The lowest two bits (bit 1 and bit 0) of the selector are combined to define the privilege of the request, where the values of 0 and 3 represent the highest and the lowest privilege, respectively.

With the CS value 0x23, bit 1 and 0 is **3**, meaning "lowest privilege". Bit 2 is **0**, meaning **GDT**, and bit 3 to bit 15 is 4, meaning we get **index 4** from the global descriptor table (GDT).

This is how far I have been able to dig so far.

Comment: The 2 lowest bits in the selector are "privilege level". 3 is least privileged (user) and 0 is most priveleged. Not `priority`. Possibly you just got the words mixed up.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. Maybe we should fix Wikipedia also.