# Polymorphism and defining a list of different objects in C++

Tags: c++

Why does my code return error? I've defined a parent class called Shape and two derived classes. I'm trying to store objects defined by the classes and store them inside a list.

```
# include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Shape{
    public:
        virtual double area(const double &height, const double &weight) const = 0;
};

class Triangle: public Shape{
   public:
       double height, weight;
       Triangle(double height, double weight): height(height), weight(weight){}
   double area(){
       return (height*weight)/2;
   }
};

class Rectangle: public Shape{
    public:
        double height, weight;
        Rectangle(double height, double weight): height(height), weight(weight){}
    double area(){
        return height*weight;
    }
};

Shape *shapes[3];
shapes[0] = new Triangle(2, 1);
shapes[1] = new Rectangle(3, 2);
shapes[2] = new Rectangle(5, 2);

double * show(Shape *shapes){
    double arr[3];
    for (int i=0; i < 3; i++){
        arr[i] = shapes[i].area();
    }
    return arr;
}

int main(){
    double arr[3] = show(shapes);
    cout << arr[0] << endl;
    cout << arr[1] << endl;
    cout << arr[2] << endl;
}
```

But I receive these two errors:

> error: 'shapes' does not name a type
>   Shapes[0] = new Trangle(2,1);
>
> error: cannot convert 'shape**' to 'shape*' 
>   double arr[3] = show(shapes);

Comment: `shapes[0] = new Triangle(2, 1);` etc - you can't have code in the global scope.  Move those statements inside `main()`.

Comment: Also, `show()` returns a pointer to a local variable.  That's UB.

Comment: Besides Sid S's reply, Your ``Shape* shapes[3];`` defines an array of size 3 of  type ``Shape*``. The name of an array is a pointer to the first element (let's not talk about decay here), so ``shapes`` has a type of ``Shape**``. Your ``shapes[i].area()`` should be ``shapes[i]->area()``. Your pure virtual function ``area()`` isn't properly overrided in your derived class.

Comment: @Sid S. I've done what you told me, but I receive this error: Invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'Triangle'.

Comment: @szppeter - Sorry, that's wrong.  The name of an array is not a pointer.   The name of an array can be used *as if* it is a pointer in some contexts, and implicitly converted to a pointer in some contexts (what some people call "decay"), but it is not a pointer.   Certainly, an array of `Shape *` and a `Shape **` are different things entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has several problems:

1. Your abstract base class `Shape` has a pure virtual function `area()` which accepts parameters, but your derived class does not. So it makes your derived class `abstract` too, so you cannot initialize an derived class object.
2. You cannot declared an array of pointer `Shapes* shapes[3];` and then assign them seperately in the global scope. That's the 1st error you are getting. More complete explanation see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51886189/can-c-have-code-in-the-global-scope)
3. When you call your `show(shapes)` function, `shapes` is a name of `Shapes*` array, it decays to a pointer to the first element. The resulting type should be `Shapes**`, that's the 2nd error you are getting.
4. Your `shapes[i]`in the `show()` function is a pointer pointing to an object, so you should use `->` instead of `.`
5. Your `double arr[3];` is an array on the stack, so after the function is finished and return, the contents are destoryed. Returning the pointer to the destoried element is undefined.
6. You did not `delete` all the object created by `new`, causing memory leak.

The minimum changes to your code to work properly is:

```cpp
# include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Shape {
public:
    virtual double area() const = 0;
};

class Triangle : public Shape {
public:
    double height, weight;
    Triangle(double height, double weight) : height(height), weight(weight) {}
    double area() const override {    //add override to let compiler check for correctness
        return (height * weight) / 2;
    }
};

class Rectangle : public Shape {
public:
    double height, weight;
    Rectangle(double height, double weight) : height(height), weight(weight) {}
    double area()const override {
        return height * weight;
    }
};

Shape* shapes[3] = { new Triangle(2, 1),  new Rectangle(3, 2) ,new Rectangle(5, 2) };

double* show(Shape** shapes) {
    double* arr = new double[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        arr[i] = shapes[i]->area();
        delete shapes[i];    //free the object pointed in shapes[]
    }
    return arr;
}

int main() {
    double* arr = show(shapes);
    cout << arr[0] << endl;
    cout << arr[1] << endl;
    cout << arr[2] << endl;
    delete[] arr;
}
```

But there are some recommendations to improve, like creating object on the stack without using `new` instead of heap, and using `std::array` to create arrays, etc.

Comment: What version of C++ should I use?

Comment: @bitWise The ``override`` keyword is introduced in C++11, but you can removed it (**!strongly unrecommend!**) to make it compatible with C++98, the oldest standard. This functioning code is very "bad" if using new standard is possible.